# Merging and Sorting 2 Queries With Php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the result of two queries from the CodeIgniter Framework which I can access with the for each loop in this way for each query

```
foreach ($query->result() as row){
       $data['email']= $row->email;
}
```

I need to merge the data of the 2 queries, to sort by email and to display them at end.

Does anyone knows? I tried with array_merge but I could get far .

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you merge and sort it in mysql query and get result that you want ?
When you merge arrays did you try [sorting the array](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)  ?

Comment: How can I merge 2 queries in MySQL?

Comment: To have the job done is possible. 

One need to set the format of the result of the queries in 

     arr1 =$query->result_array();

after it merge the 2 array

     array_merge (arr1,arr2);

and at end sort with multisort function of php in which I remind a note to see how to order

array in a specific key order in php manual.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) function in mysql.